# How does redux tookit query create methods dynamically in typescript?

Tags: redux-toolkit

I need to do the same thing that redux toolkit query does for creating dynamic methods with types, in typescript. Like in this example:

```
export const pokemonApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'pokemonApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPokemonByName: builder.query<Pokemon, string>({
      query: (name) => `pokemon/${name}`,
    }),
  }),
})

// Export hooks for usage in functional components, which are
// auto-generated based on the defined endpoints
export const { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } = pokemonApi
```

typescript validates that `useGetPokemonByNameQuery` is a function of `pokemonApi` and gets the right parameters too.

Answer (score 1):

It's a combination of [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) and [Template Type Literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) using [Key Remapping via
as](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as).

The [code in question](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/95131ebb62fb80b315af21cf605ad084bd8a9e4d/packages/toolkit/src/query/react/versionedTypes/ts41Types.ts#L11):

```
export type HooksWithUniqueNames<Definitions extends EndpointDefinitions> =
  keyof Definitions extends infer Keys
    ? Keys extends string
      ? Definitions[Keys] extends { type: DefinitionType.query }
        ? {
            [K in Keys as `use${Capitalize<K>}Query`]: UseQuery<
              Extract<Definitions[K], QueryDefinition<any, any, any, any>>
            >
          } &
            {
              [K in Keys as `useLazy${Capitalize<K>}Query`]: UseLazyQuery<
                Extract<Definitions[K], QueryDefinition<any, any, any, any>>
              >
            }
        : Definitions[Keys] extends { type: DefinitionType.mutation }
        ? {
            [K in Keys as `use${Capitalize<K>}Mutation`]: UseMutation<
              Extract<Definitions[K], MutationDefinition<any, any, any, any>>
            >
          }
        : never
      : never
    : never
```